# PDF/A compatibility processing color gradients in Ghostscript

Tags: gradient, pdfbox, ghostscript, tikz, pdfa

I have [this PDF image](https://linx.li/8xvg2x86.pdf) which contains color gradients. I want to convert it to a PDF/A with Ghostscript 9.22. My command is

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -dCompressFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPDFA -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dFastWebView=true -sOutputFile=$2 $1
```

but I got the following errors when trying to validate the result with PDFBox preflight:

> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing
>
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing
>
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing
>
> 2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "f" can't be used without Color Profile

I thought I have to tell Ghostscript to use a color profile in the output, so I tried these parameters separately and together

```
-sOutputICCProfile=/usr/share/color/icc/CoatedFOGRA39.icc -sProfileOut=/usr/share/color/icc/CoatedFOGRA39.icc -sPostRenderProfile=/usr/share/color/icc/CoatedFOGRA39.icc
```

without luck (I have the profile in that path).

What can I do?

**Note**: The figure is built with TikZ and is part of a document: I actually would like to have the whole document to be compliant, but it fails just on this figure.

Comment: On the TeX side, the culprit is `shader=interp` from TikZ. Removing it, I'm able to get a PDF/A with the first command above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified a PDFA_def.ps file. This is a requirement, it is not optional, and you must edit the contents to be correct. You can only specify the DestOutputProfile using the means outlined in the PDFA_def.ps file (basically a bunch of pdfmarks).

The steps are documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/VectorDevices.htm#PDFA)

I'm not certain, but I would not use FastWebView to create a PDF/A file, I'm not sure that linearised files can be PDF/A compliant. Its also more or less pointless anyway.

Comment: The page reports `input.ps`, so a PS instead of a PDF? What if I can't produce the PS?

Also, I validated correctly FastWebView PDF/As previously. Why do you say it's pointless?

Comment: The documentation uses input.ps simply as an example of where the input filename goes. Its an example, nothing more. Linearized PDF files are, basically, pointless, because at best they load page 1 more quickly, nothing else, and most PDF viewers simply ignore linearisation.

Comment: You're right, it works with `input.pdf` as well (even if trivial, they might clarify it for non experts like me). The only problem is that `/ICCProfile` won't recognize absolute paths on my system, so I had to put my icc file into the compilation folder. I still can get linear PDF/As, therefore it may be pointless, but it doesn't harm. :-)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, a Linearized PDF file is larger than the same file when not linearized, some people seem to feel that's important.

Comment: If by ICCProfile you mean the entry in PDFA_def.ps, it most certainly does recognise absolute path names.But if you set -dSAFER then you prevent Ghostscript accessing files in almost all parts of the file system. That's what SAFER is for......